# Multilanguage website - articles listing issue in joomla

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I have a website build with joomla, I have it in two languages, English and Albanian.

The issue is that in a specified module that should show articles in pagination, in English it shows 5 articles per page, in Albanian 3 articles per page.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your website url at least

Comment: I think that the problem is related to a different publication as menu. Go to menu items of each languages and control that they are the same (i.e., number of articles, order, etc.)

Comment: will do , thank you

Comment: that worked perfectly , thanks Jegger

Comment: I am glad to have helped you. You can update the question as solved.